# Bootstrap Navbar link background height

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3, navbar

I have made my navbar taller in bootstrap using

```
.navbar {
    padding-top: 15px;
    padding-bottom: 15px;
}
```

However now the background of the active navbar link looks like this
[image: example]

How do I get the pictured grey background to span the full height of the navbar? I tried various things such as increasing the padding, and this does make it taller, but it doesn't actually extend over the purple, which is what I want.

Example here: http://jsfiddle.net/pjxd9cka/

```css
@import url('https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css');

.navbar {
  padding-top: 15px;
  padding-bottom: 15px;
  border: 0;
  border-radius: 0;
  margin-bottom: 0;
  font-size: 12px;
  letter-spacing: 5px;
}
```

```html
<header class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top bs-docs-nav" role="banner">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button class="navbar-toggle" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".bs-navbar-collapse">
        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      </button>
      <a href="./" class="navbar-brand">Bootstrap 3 Menu Generator</a>
    </div>
    <nav class="collapse navbar-collapse bs-navbar-collapse" role="navigation">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li>
          <a href="#">Getting started</a>
        </li>
        <li class="dropdown">
          <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Dropdown <b class="caret"></b></a>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu">
            <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">One more separated link</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="#">Components</a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="#">JavaScript</a>
        </li>
        <li class="active">
          <a href="#">Customize</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
  </div>
</header>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Please share the HTML and the rest of the CSS for the navbar so we can understand what's going on.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/pjxd9cka/1/

If you look here you can see what I mean here. When the active link is selected I want the background to span the whole height of the navbar, rather than the default height

Answer (score 1):

The active element is what's producing the highlighted color, meaning you need to make the active element larger if you want it to grow.

One solution is to add your additional padding to the `a` elements inside the menu instead of to the outer menu container. Since bootstrap's default padding is 15px, you'll need to make it 15+15=30px top and bottom. It may also be different padding for different media screen sizes. Once you do this, in order to keep the `navbar-header` aligned, you'll need to add a margin to the top of that too.

```
.navbar {
  border: 0;
  border-radius: 0;
  margin-bottom: 0;
  font-size: 12px;
  letter-spacing: 5px;
  background-color: teal;
}
.navbar-header {
  margin-top: 15px;
}
.nav li a {
  padding-top: 30px;
  padding-bottom: 30px;
}
```

Here's a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/1nj8xn80/) illustrating this.

Answer (score 0):

A quick fix would be to add a negative margin to your links.

`.navbar a {
    margin-top: -15px;
    margin-bottom: -15px;`

Or perhaps a better method would be to change play with the height of the links.

`.navbar a {
    height: 100%;
    margin-top: 0;
    margin-bottom: 0;`

Comment: Doing that would make the navbar the default height again. I want to keep the navbar at the larger custom height I have it set at, and make sure the active link background is also that same height.

Answer (score 0):

I've redefined paddings and margins for three other classes instead of the `.navbar` class:

- `.navbar-brand`
- `.navbar-toggle`
- `.navbar-nav > li > a`

Please check the result: http://jsfiddle.net/glebkema/hwk7kjmo/

```css
@import url('https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css');

.navbar {
  /*
  padding-top: 15px;
  padding-bottom: 15px;
  */
  border: 0;
  border-radius: 0;
  margin-bottom: 0;
  font-size: 12px;
  letter-spacing: 5px;
}

.navbar-brand {
  height: 80px; /* 50px by default */
  padding-bottom: 30px; /* 15px by default */
  padding-top: 30px;
}
.navbar-toggle {
  margin-bottom: 20px; /* 8px by default */
  margin-top: 20px;
  padding-bottom: 12px; /* 9px by default */
  padding-top: 12px;
}
@media (min-width: 768px) {
  .navbar-nav > li > a {
    padding-bottom: 30px; /* 15px by default */
    padding-top: 30px;
  }
}
```

```html
<header class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top bs-docs-nav" role="banner">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button class="navbar-toggle" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".bs-navbar-collapse">
        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      </button>
      <a href="./" class="navbar-brand">Bootstrap 3 Menu Generator</a>
    </div>
    <nav class="collapse navbar-collapse bs-navbar-collapse" role="navigation">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li>
          <a href="#">Getting started</a>
        </li>
        <li class="dropdown">
          <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Dropdown <b class="caret"></b></a>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu">
            <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">One more separated link</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="#">Components</a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="#">JavaScript</a>
        </li>
        <li class="active">
          <a href="#">Customize</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
  </div>
</header>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```